# How do you copy a constexpr array to another constexpr array with std::copy?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, c++11, constexpr

In the following code, I create an array of length 6 and initialize it with 1, 2 and 3 in the first 3 elements. Then I copy the first 3 elements to the last 3 elements. Then I print all the elements in order.

```
std::array<int, 6> bar = {1, 2, 3};

int main(){
    // Copy the first 3 elements to the last 3 elements
    std::copy(bar.begin(), bar.end() - 3, bar.end() - 3);

    // Print all the elements of bar
    for(auto& i: bar) std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

It works fine, but when I try to make the array `constexpr` it no-longer compiles:

```
constexpr std::array<int, 6> bar = {1, 2, 3};

int main(){
    // Copy the first 3 elements to the last 3 elements
    std::copy(bar.begin(), bar.end() - 3, bar.end() - 3); // Won't compile!

    // Print all the elements of bar
    for(auto& i: bar) std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

Compiling with `g++ -std=c++14 main.cpp -o main` I get the following error message:

```
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algobase.h: In instantiation of ‘_OI std::__copy_move_a(_II, _II, _OI) [with bool _IsMove = false; _II = const int*; _OI = const int*]’:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algobase.h:438:45:   required from ‘_OI std::__copy_move_a2(_II, _II, _OI) [with bool _IsMove = false; _II = const int*; _OI = const int*]’
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algobase.h:471:8:   required from ‘_OI std::copy(_II, _II, _OI) [with _II = const int*; _OI = const int*]’
main.cpp:115:53:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algobase.h:402:44: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::__copy_move<false, true, std::random_access_iterator_tag>::__copy_m(const int*&, const int*&, const int*&)’
                        _Category>::__copy_m(__first, __last, __result);
                                            ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algobase.h:373:9: note: candidate: template<class _Tp> static _Tp* std::__copy_move<_IsMove, true, std::random_access_iterator_tag>::__copy_m(const _Tp*, const _Tp*, _Tp*) [with _Tp = _Tp; bool _IsMove = false]
         __copy_m(const _Tp* __first, const _Tp* __last, _Tp* __result)
         ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algobase.h:373:9: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algobase.h:402:44: note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter ‘_Tp’ (‘int’ and ‘const int’)
                        _Category>::__copy_m(__first, __last, __result);
```

I don't understand this error message at all. Is `std::copy` not `constexpr`? If it isn't, it should be, right? Does my code would work if `std::copy` was `constexpr`?

Comment: If the array is const, you can't change it.

Comment: I do not have much experience with new C++ feature but it does not make sense to declare an array constexpr if you want to modify it afterwards. Either, the array is constant or not.

Comment: @latedeveloper How to I make stuff at compiletime that isn't 'const' then?

Comment: @WillyGoat - exactly... what do you want make at compile time? Duplicate a list of values in an array?

Comment: @Willy I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: @max66 I'm implementing something that uses a very large array of precomputed values which wrap around once. I can't do this without printing out values and copy-pasting them into my code?

Comment: @WillyGoat - a couple of other question. (1) what do you mean with "very large"? (2) is ok for you if the array become the member of a templare `struct`?

Comment: @max66 By large I mean 512 elements. I initialize the first 256, then copy them to the last 256, similar to my example. And I don't mind a `struct`

Comment: @WillyGoat - the number (256*2) can be a problem (but I'm not sure) but... modified my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should make a constexpr function. `constexpr` imply const, but not inside the scope of a `constexpr` function.

```
constexpr auto get_bar() {
    std::array<int, 6> bar = {1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0};

    copy(bar.begin(), bar.end() - 3, bar.end() - 3);

    return bar;
}
```

However, you will need to write your own version of `copy` because it's not marked as `constexpr` in the standard library.

Changing the value of a compile time array does not make sense, it's the same thing as asking the compiler to change the type of a variable at runtime. The compiler don't even exist during runtime. However, a constexpr function is executed by the compiler, so it's still make sense to ask it to mutate values. This is why the code above make sense.

Note that most of `std::array` accessors are not `constexpr` until C++17.

Comment: Also note that [`std::array<T, n>::begin()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/begin), [`std::array<T, n>::end()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/end) and all other accessors are only `constexpr` since C++17.

Comment: @yurikilochek Indeed, I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: Thanks. I really appreciate your second sentence. I've been confused about the const-ness of `constexpr`. To me it still doesn't make sense that something has to be `const` if you want it to be evaluated at compiletime. What if you need to precompute a huge array that gets altered at runtime?

Comment: @WillyGoat I added a paragraph to the answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

`constexpr` imply `const`.

Your `std::copy` try to modify a `const` variable.

**--- EDIT ---**

The OP ask

> I'm implementing something that uses a very large array of precomputed values which wrap around once. I can't do this without printing out values and copy-pasting them into my code?

What about something as follows?

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

template <int ... I>
struct foo
 { std::array<int, 2U*sizeof...(I)> bar { { I..., I... } }; };

int main()
 {
   foo<2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13> v;

   for ( auto const & i : v.bar )
      std::cout << i << ", ";

   // the for print 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13,

   std::cout << std::endl;
 }
```

Comment: How do get around that? I don't mind the array being `const` at runtime, but I'd like to be able to edit it programmatically at compiletime.

Comment: Don't make it const. Why would you make it const if you want to change it?

Comment: @WillyGoat - a `const` (`constexpr`) variable can only be initialized; you have to insert all values in initialization; and if you want to do something at compiletime, has to be `constexpr` or templape arguments.

Comment: I appreciate the edit. That's some crazy c++, but I like Guillaume's solution the most. Thanks! :)

Comment: @WillyGoat - you're wellcome :)