# Converting a const char* to char* at compile-time

Tags: c++, constants, constexpr, compile-time

In my project, I need the user to input a string, and the string that is typed is `const char*` by default (with using quotation marks). In my project, I also need to modify these strings, so I cannot really use `const`.

So I thought about transforming the `const char*` into a `char*` with the following function:

Not 100% sure this is the problem (since it crashes for me) but I believe the problem is that the `New` string does not have enough memory to store the whole string. I tried sort of allocating it memory by writing like this:

```
const char* szOldString = "Test";
char* szNewString[0x1024];
noconst(&szOldString, &szNewString, 5);
```

This also did not work considering my parameters and the constexpr.

---

I am wondering if anybody knows any cool hacks I can use to make this work. I have been working on this for some time so the solution might be an obvious one and I just cannot see it. If that's the case, my bad :D

Comment: You can't really modify actual memory at compile time, even if you do use a real buffer large enough. What is the actual compile-time problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: You have a bad design in your code. If you pass in `char*` that are actually `const char*`, that means hat your function may modify the input, which is bad. Rewrite the code that wats a `const char*`, that's where the modification must be introduced.

Comment: I know I can't, but I am working on this for the past 5+ hours and I was getting desperate. I am making a string encryption class where you just enter text normally and it gets encrypted at compile-time and only decrypts at run-time when it is used so you cannot map any strings or memory without opening the application at which point I will add more protection. Thought it would be an interesting project and saw other people that did the exact thing before so it must be possible somehow. I don't want to copy&paste though

Comment: Is it on purpose that you use a fixed (arbitrary) memory address for your new string ?

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher So you are saying that if I will use the New char* string, my function may modify the output? How could this happen unless I am converting from an UNICODE string?

Comment: I think you meant `(*New)[i] = (*Old)[i]`. not `*New[i] = *Old[i]`.

Comment: "Decrypt at compile time", means that what was encrypted would be in clear text in the executable file.

Comment: @Christophe It's not a string, I wanted to allocate memory. Is that not what I was doing?

Comment: @Christophe I meant decrypt at run time my bad :D

Comment: There is so much wrong with this at so many different levels that I just don't know where to start.

Comment: @KamilCuk Wouldn't that be exactly the same? I mean what exactly could I even get if I dereference New[i] for example? I will change it anyway though, thanks. Also, I don't want to use std::string since 1st: It will make it easier for REs to find all the strings 2nd: it's possible for me to make it without that and why choose the easy way 3rd: I swear I had another reason but I'm too tired to remember

Comment: No, you don't allocate memory here.  You consider that memory at address 0x1024 is available.  Consider `char szNewString [0x1024]` if you want to allocate a fixed size memory of size 0x1024.  Or `char* szNewString = new char[0x1024]` for dynamic allocation.

Comment: I will try the first one although it will mess with my current parameters when I try to enter it. Also, the conversion has to happen at compile time so no dynamic allocation @RayButterworth well that is not very helpful, please tell me what's up

Comment: No it is not. `*New[i]` means `*(New[i])` which means to first increment the pointer by `sizeof(char*) * i` times, then decrement it. It's very different. And it is undefined behavior. There is only one `char*` pointer to where the `char **` pointer point's to, it's not an  array of pointers. `*(New[i])` means `New[i][0]`. You want `New[0][i]`. Ans is there any reason why don't you `std::string(szOldString)` ??

Comment: You are right, but *New automatically points to the first element of the char* so New[0][i] is the same as (*New)[i]

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast

Comment: In your function, what do you think *New[i] = *Old[i]" does?  Try "(*New)[i] = (*Old)[i]".  In the main part, what do you think "New = 0x1024" does?  Perhaps "New[0x1024]"?  What do you think "0x1024" means"? It's not 1k.  Why do you call the function with Size=4?  Don't you want to copy the end-of-string character?  Why are you looking for "cool hacks" when you don't even understand what library functions are already available for copying data, what pointers are, what *x[i] syntax means, what memory allocation is, what "0x" notation means, what ... ?  Everything about this question is just wr

Comment: @RayButterworth Yeah man I made a lot of newbie commands, but I am really sleep deprived. I have come far though without any help so far into this project. 1st: I'm not sure how I could use szNew as a parameter if I type szNew[0x1024], it was just an idea. Also, what functions can I use to do this?

Comment: @L.C. So I tried this. The compiler does not complain anymore, but the characters are not changing still

Comment: This function is just a bad rewrite of `strncpy` or `std::copy` family function. Just call `std::copy` inside a constexpr template function which allocates an `std::array` with you can then return, just like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41600157/how-do-you-copy-a-constexpr-array-to-another-constexpr-array-with-stdcopy)

Comment: Why do you pass `New` and `Old` as pointers to pointers? Why not just pass the pointers by value since you don't change that value? I think Kamil Cuk is dead on -- if you fix all the issues with this function, it will wind up being a slightly specialized rewrite of `std::copy`.

Comment: @KamilCuk I cannot call copy or strncpy from inside a constexpr function

Comment: @DavidSchwartz because of the way I initialize them, doing it the other way would make my code even more unreadable. Also I doubt there is ever going to be a problem with it, but if there is ill definitely change it

Comment: I don't think there is a `constexpr` version that fits your constraints.

Comment: I am currently looking at another guy that did something similar: https://github.com/urShadow/StringObfuscator/blob/master/str_obfuscator.hpp and trying to understand his code. It's damn possible has to be. And to all the pseudo intellectuals downvoting my post, you should actually comment here and tell me why my post was stupid

Answer (score 2):

The easier way is to use the function `strncpy` (which is more secure than just using `strcpy`).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  //char oldString[]= "Hello World!";
  const char* oldString = "Hello World!";
  char newString[40];

  /* copy to sized buffer (overflow safe): */
  strncpy ( newString, oldString, sizeof(newString) );

  cout << newString;  

    return 0;
}
```

Another way is to allocate with malloc space for where you wish to copy the string.
After, you can modify it as your please.

Comment: `overflow safe` and the oldest problems, `strncpy` it is, but `cout << newString` is not : /

Comment: It is what I would've done, but I have to do this in a constexpr and it does not allow me to use functions like that

Comment: There is no benefit from using `strncpy` here instead of `strcpy`; the target array is clearly large enough. If it wasn’t, this use of `strncpy` would not be “overflow safe”. Read the documentation for `strncpy` carefully. Or just try it: make `newString` smaller and see what happens. Passing a length does not automatically make a function “more secure”.

Comment: Why `string.h`? Also how does this solve OP's original question?

Comment: @PeteBecker, I am just providing a basic example to him. Plus, between strcat, strcpy and strncpy, I prefer strncpy. The issue with strncpy is when you don't provide a null termination in every case at the destination. There is another option which is to use strlcpy.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher there was no part of the question that indicated that you couldn't use a library to solve it.

Comment: @acarlstein Well its kind of obvious considering how these functions work and the fact that I said I want to do it compile-time (with constexpr)

Comment: @acarlstein except that you didn't show how to integrate it, what to look for (in terms of issues) and how it fits OP's constraints.

Comment: Sorry @AAAbbbCCCddd, I didn't see your comment below the question about compile-time. I see that you updated the question twice already so I will have to read again what you did.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher I provided an example for which the user can implement as he or she wishes. Where is your solution?

Comment: There is no solution to OP's problem except properly handling `const char*`.